# Reducing the dimensionality of word embeddings

Tags: nlp, dimensionality-reduction, word-embeddings

I trained word embeddings with 300 dimensions. Now, I would like to have word embeddings with 50 dimensions: is it better to retrain the word embeddings with 50 dimensions, or can I use some dimensionality reduction method to scale the word embeddings with 300 dimensions down to 50 dimensions?

Comment: what method of word embedding are you using?

Comment: @lollercoaster word2vec and GloVe.

Answer (score 7):

There is a paper on this subject called

> Simple and Effective Dimensionality Reduction for Word Embeddings, Vikas Raunak

You can read it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03629)

You can also find the implementation [here](https://github.com/vyraun/Half-Size)

In my opinion it works quite well

Answer (score 4):

[t-distributed stochastic neighbor embedding (t-SNE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) is often used for dimensionality reduction in word embeddings. t-SNE maintains the relative relationships between the vectors.

Most often t-SNE is used for visualization, thus reducing the dimensions to 2 or 3. It could also reduce the dimensions down to 50.